# php- switch fails before i select an option

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm having a problem with php switch function. I know it must be simple, but i'm just learning and I can't seem to find the right way to code it.
This is the issue: It works fine when you click any of the options, but it sends an error msg when I first load up the page...

```
<body>
    <?php include ('./header.php')?>

    <section>
        <div class="btn">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.php?opcion=op1">Opcion 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.php?opcion=op2">Opcion 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.php?opcion=op3">Opcion 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php 
            if(isset ($_GET['opcion'])) {

            
            switch($_GET['opcion']) {
                case 'op1' :
                    $nombre = 'Magnus Carlsen';
                    $posicion = '1';
                    $puntaje = '2840';
                    $img = './magnus.jpg';
                break;
                case 'op2' :
                    $nombre = 'Ian Nepomniatchi';
                    $posicion = '2';
                    $puntaje = '2812';
                    $img = './nepo.jpeg';
                break;
                case 'op3' :
                    $nombre = 'Ding Liren';
                    $posicion = '3';
                    $puntaje = '2760';
                    $img = './ding.jpg';
                break;
                }
            }
            else {
                
            }
            
            ?>
             <div class="show">
                    <h3><?php echo $nombre?></h2>
                    <h4><?php echo $posicion?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $puntaje?></p>
                    <div class="contenedor_img">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="foto">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now, I suppose the "show" div shouldn't be there... but it doesn't responde well when i move it around either...

this are the errors:

Warning: Undefined variable $nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\proyectos\PHP\index.php on line 53

Warning: Undefined variable $posicion in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\proyectos\PHP\index.php on line 54

Warning: Undefined variable $puntaje in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\proyectos\PHP\index.php on line 55
foto

Comment: and do you get any errors?

Comment: Just added the errors in the post, forgot to do it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the form is not submitted, you do not enter your switch. that means your `$nombre`, `$posicion`, `$puntaje` and most probably `$img` are not defined. There are 2 ways to unblock yourself.

Option 1,  give a default value to these variables

```
// here you can define your variables
$nombre = 'no number';
$posicion = 'no position';
$puntaje = 'empty';
$img = '';
if (isset ($_GET['opcion'])) {
    switch ($_GET['opcion']) {
        case 'op1' :
            $nombre = 'Magnus Carlsen';
            $posicion = '1';
            $puntaje = '2840';
            $img = './magnus.jpg';
            break;
        case 'op2' :
            $nombre = 'Ian Nepomniatchi';
            $posicion = '2';
            $puntaje = '2812';
            $img = './nepo.jpeg';
            break;
        case 'op3' :
            $nombre = 'Ding Liren';
            $posicion = '3';
            $puntaje = '2760';
            $img = './ding.jpg';
            break;
    }
} else {
}
```

or you can check to see if user has submitted the form and only then try to echo the variables. You can do this by surrounding the html in an if statement.

```
<?php if(isset ($_GET['opcion'])) { ?>
<div class="show">
    <h3><?php echo $nombre?></h2>
        <h4><?php echo $posicion?></h4>
        <p><?php echo $puntaje?></p>
        <div class="contenedor_img">
            <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" alt="foto">
        </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: as a side note, you are also missing the default case in your switch

Comment: what should i put as default?

Comment: this depends on your business logic. what should happen if form gets submitted but opcion is not op1, op2 or op3?

Comment: mmm... not really an opcion. its a list of chess players and it should show some info of each one when you press thier name.